# Vue Router chokes on import of Graphql-js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, vue-router

I have a module that imports the `parse` function from `graphql-js`,

```
// api.ts

import { parse } from "graphql";

export async function api(source: string): Promise<Response> {
  const ast = parse(source);

  // do more stuff ...
}
```

I then use `api` in a dynamically imported view with `vue-router`.

However, navigating to the route fails with,

```
SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
```

I've pin pointed the error to the `graphql` import statement. If that is removed, the error goes away.

I've been trying to sort this out for hours.

What might be causing this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: does the error include information about a specific line of code in a specific file - I take it this error is in a browser?

Comment: Yes, it's in the browser. The error is reported at `vue-router.mjs:3451:20`, which is error handling code in `vue-router`.

Comment: I just unlocked a different error by uncommenting the import, `[hmr] Failed to reload /src/views/View.vue. This could be due to syntax errors or importing non-existent modules. (see errors above)`. Weird thing is that the offending module is used in some unit tests that work perfectly fine.

Comment: `which is error handling code` can you look at the error trace to see which line of code actually threw the error

Comment: It starts at `mountElement` in `runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5213`.